# Element Not Be Pushed ViewPort When Display Out Of Screen

Tags: html, css

I have a span like this:

```
<section class="content">
     <p class="title" style="font-size: 200px; opacity: 0.1">Text Here</p>
</section>
```

and my CSS:

```
.content{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 450px;
}
.fly-title{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I want to set this `<p>` `margin-left: 110%` but it pull my view to left and my webpage have a scrollbar at bottom.

See my images for detail:

[image]

How to make my `<p>` at this position.

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you would like? Do you want the `<p>` to be positioned to the left, you just don't want a scroll bar?

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I will upload my picture now. I don't want a bottom scrollbar and my web view not be pushed to left.

Comment: So, like http://jsfiddle.net/uth2k9ub/1/ ?

Comment: Yes. I know `overflow: hidden` to make this but it's not make effect in this example.

Comment: So, you want the effect of overflow:hidden, without using overflow:hidden?

Comment: I have use overflow: hidden for my section but it's not make effect.

Comment: In what way does Jacob's fiddle not do what you want?

Comment: Jacob's fiddle is exactly result I want. I still do with this code. But, in my project, it's not worked.

Comment: So what is different about your project? Does it have more CSS you're not showing here? Test for yourself with the browser's web dev tools; you can find what it is that overrides the "overflow:hidden".